# Laravel Upgrade Error With Whoops

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just updated my Laravel 5.4.23 to 5.5 and tried running my tests for PHPUnit and I am receiving the following error and I am trying to scour around the internet and find out people who have done so and have received the same error message but have not had any luck.

Has anyone received this error?

```
Call to undefined method Whoops\Handle\PrettyPageHandler::setApplicationPaths()
```

Comment: Have you deleted `composer.lock`, run `composer install`, and then `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: I still received the same error.

Comment: updated **phpunit/phpunit** dependency to ~6.0 and **filp/whoops** version ~2.0 ?

Comment: Yes those are updated to those versions and still the same.

Answer (score 5):

setApplicationPaths() doesn't exist in the 2.0.0 release of the filp/whoops library. Essentially, it's not a problem with Laravel 5.5 but with that specific version of Whoops. I experienced the same issue until I updated the library version I was using to the newest stable version of Whoops (2.1.10), which I did by changing the dependency version in my composer.json file `"filp/whoops" : "~2.1.10"` Once you make that change, run `composer update` and the error should go away.

(1/5/2018) Editing to add that this doesn't appear to be an issue in later releases of Laravel 5.5, so changes to the version of `filp/whoops` should not be necessary at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing all the caches via `php artisan cache:clear` or `php artisan view:clear`?

Comment: Yes I have. and still receive the same.

Comment: Did you add `filp/whoops` to your composer.json in the require-dev section?

Comment: Yes I did add it to the composer.json file.